# Mov file has more frames than written/Possible iOS AVAsset writer usage issue

Tags: ios, video, mov, formats

I am manually generated a .mov video file.

Here is a link to an example file: [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13974932/Linknode/video.mov), I wrote a few image frames, and then after a long break wrote approximately 15 image frames just to emphasise my point for debuting purposes. When I extract images from the video ffmpeg returns around 400 frames instead of the 15-20 I expected. Is this because the API i am using is inserting these image files automatically? Is it a part of the .mov file format that requires this? Or is it due to the way the library is extracting the image frames from the video? I have tried searching the internet but could not arrive at an answer.

My use case is that I am trying to write the current "sensor data" (from core motion) from core motion while writing a video. For each frame I receive from the camera, I use "AppendPixelBuffer" to write the frame to the video and then

Thanks for any help. The end result is I want a 1:1 ratio of Frames in the video to rows in the CSV file. I have confirmed I am writing the CSV file correctly using various counters etc. So my issue is cleariy the understanding of the movie format or API.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**
It looks like your `ffmpeg` extractor is wrong. To extract only the timestamped frames (and not frames sampled at 24Hz) in your file, try this:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mov  -r 1/1 image-%03d.jpeg
```

This gives me the 20 frames expected.

**OLD ANSWER**

`ffprobe` reports that your video has a frame rate of 2.19 frames/s and a duration of 17s, which gives 2.19 * 17 = 37 frames, which is closer to your expected 15-20 than ffmpeg's 400.

So maybe the ffmpeg extractor is at fault?

Hard to say if you don't show how you encode and decode the file.

Comment: Hi, "ffmpeg -i movie.mov image%%4d.jpg"is what I am using to extract the frames from the movie. I am using the AVFoundation API's for creating the video. I have pasted the key bits below.

I append the pixel buffers using :
CMTime time = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);

Some of the configuration:
  self.assetWriter = [AVAssetWriter assetWriterWithURL:imageDirectory
                                                fileType:AVFileTypeMPEG4
                                                   error:&error];
AVAssetWriterInput output settings:AVVideoCodecKey :AVVideoCodecJPEG,

Comment: Thanks for your help, when I am back on my system I will test it out and get back to you.

Comment: Sorry, I was on holiday from work for a while. Now I can't seem to create videos to replicate it! Even if I extract them the old way - there is a 1 to 1 ratio of actual frames recorded and frames extracted (with eh old command). If I ever manage to replicate it again I will update this answer though.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Ah I managed to replicate it again (had to record from a different iPad model).

Your answer does not seem to be correct. I have a video with 1420 frames, and in this case it spits out too few frames (83 in this case).

Comment: Can you link to the new video?